# Embedding an application inside another application

Tags: java, swing, embed

I'm sure some of you noticed that if you have Acrobat Reader ( or any other pdf viewer ) , and open a pdf in Firefox , you will see it embedded inside your tab . Is there any way to embed an application in a JFrame ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rather tricky. In general, native application such and Adobe Reader does not provide component which can be embedded into swing application. But in Windows there is COM/OLE approach which allows embedding of application together. This [article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t70811.html) can help you. It points on two project JCOM and JACOB which allows such embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but that application will need to provide JComponent version which is embeddable.