# JavaFX and embedded applications

Tags: java, embed, javafx

I have just started digging into JavaFX and have a requirement that I am not sure if I can fulfill with JavaFX.  Does anyone know if JavaFX supports embedding another application (non-java, in this case a microsoft app) in a panel? I don't (at this time) have a requirement to control anything on that application, just have it run in that panel.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Embeding applications into Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309158/embedding-an-application-inside-another-application/311343#311343). Originally asked for Swing, but it is also applicable for JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

Is the other application a Java program? As JavaFX supports Threads, and since you can instantiate Java classes in JavaFX, this should actually work, though this is just a guess.

Comment: Oops... I missed putting that info in the question. No, it is not a java application... it is (unfortunately) a microsoft one. In the end it is ok if I can't, I just need to determine if it is possible and everything I have seen so far says yes for java, no for non-java.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed other java applications,but certainly not other technology applications.I would rather suggest to reframe just your user interface in JavaFx as it would help you get a very rich user experience!

Good Luck!

Comment: I was looking for whether or not it was possible to embed a Microsoft app (really almost looking for a pass through to the GUI - I was going to add data via a separate service, which would cause the GUI to update).  Your answer is pretty much what I figured, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  Thanks.